# When would you use a List<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>> instead of a Dictionary<T1, T2>?

Tags: c#, dictionary

What is the difference between a List of KeyValuePair and a Dictionary for the same types? Is there an appropriate time to use one or the other?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

When you don't need fast lookups on key - maintaining the hashtable used by `Dictionary` has a certain overhead.

Comment: Also list insert operation is faster that the one in Dictionary

Comment: Its fields are readonly, but you can always replace the entire element in the list.

Answer (score 70):

In short, the list does not enforce uniqueness of the key, so if you need that semantic then that's what you should use.

Comment: +1 Note that dictionary doesn't enforce uniqueness of the value either!

Answer (score 30):

Dictionary is **generic type** that contains a collection of key-value pairs. Dictionary is fast for lookup operations, because is **using hash function internally**. That means, **all the keys must be unique in dictionary**.

**Consider this examples:**

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
pairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Miroslav"));
pairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Naomi"));
pairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Ingrid"));

Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, "Miroslav");
dict.Add(2, "Naomi");
dict.Add(2, "Ingrid"); // System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
```

So you should always consider two at least two things:

1. Do you want to search concrete items in dictionary?
2. Do you want to have some fields
   non-unique (for example pairs: firstname/lastname).

Comment: I think the point here is that dictionary keys must be unique where List<KeyValuePair> keys must not be unique.

Comment: @BrunoBieri List<KeyValuePair> keys *may* not be unique

Comment: I rectified your 2 yrs old comment, and you noticed that. No wonder why SO is the only trusted and most popular Q&A platform.

Answer (score 14):

The List would also be useful when you care about the order of the items.

Comment: Wouldn't [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) cover this?

Comment: Yes, but SortedDictionary cannot cover the order of the values, only the keys.

Answer (score 7):

Further to Phillip Ngan's answer, SOAP or otherwise, you cannot XML serialize objects that implements IDictionary.

> Q: Why can't I serialize hashtables?
>
> A: The XmlSerializer cannot process classes implementing the IDictionary interface. This was partly due to schedule constraints and partly due to the fact that a hashtable does not have a counterpart in the XSD type system. The only solution is to implement a custom hashtable that does not implement the IDictionary interface.

[from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx)

Comment: Paul Welter wrote a serializable XML Dictionary

https://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/444961

Answer (score 5):

In SOAP webservices for silverlight, we have found that Dictionary's do not serialize. This would be a situation where you would use a List of KeyValuePair over a Dictionary.

.

Answer (score 3):

From http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2004/09/03/225473.aspx:

> `KeyValuePair` vs. `DictionaryEntry`
>   [Krzysztof Cwalina]
>
> We discussed a problem with
>   implementation of `IEnumerable` on
>   `Dictionary<K,V>`. What type should
>   `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator().Current`
>   return? `KeyValuePair<K,V>` or
>   `DictionaryEntry`? Same for
>   `ICollection.CopyTo`. Instances of what
>   type should be copied to the array?
>
> We decided the following: `IEnumerable`
>   and `ICollection` interface
>   implementations will use
>   `KeyValuePair<K,V>` as the item type. 
>   `IDictionary` specific members
>   (`GetEnumerator` returning
>   `IDictionaryEnumerator`) will use
>   `DictionaryEntry` as the item type.
>
> The reason is that we are in a process
>   of making a change where
>   `IEnumerator<T>` would extend
>   `IEnumerator`. It would be very strange
>   if walking the hierarchy from
>   `Dictionary<K,V>`->`IEnumerable<T>`->`IEnumerable`
>   we suddenly changed the type of the
>   item returned from enumerators.