# Replace unwanted char in a list with the defined char in other list

Tags: c#

I have two `List<T>` collections. One for users search preferences and the other for unwanted characters. The requirement is to replace the unwanted chars in the first list with defined char in the second list.

I just did the replacement by looping through the first list. Then inside the loop, starts another iteration through the second list and replace each unwanted char.

```
public class Test
{
    public void DoTest()
    {
        //For test purpose, create the filter list.
        var filterList = new List<Filter>
        {
            new Filter(){ Column="UserName", Value="O'Connor", Operator="start-with"},
            new Filter(){ Column="SRCount", Value="2", Operator="Equal"}
        };
        //Replace the unwanted chars(like single quotes with double) in search string.
        UnwantedCharReplacement(filterList);
    }

    private void UnwantedCharReplacement(IList<Filter> filters)
    {
        //Get the list of 'Filter' class which contains the unwanted chars.
        var lists = from filter in filters
                    where UnwantedCharacterList.All.Any(c => filter.Value.Contains(c.Key))
                    select filter;

        //Loop through each 'Filter' list
        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            //Loop through available unwanted char list, then replace.
            UnwantedCharacterList.All.ForEach(u =>
            {
                list.Value = list.Value.Replace(u.Key, u.Value);
            });
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This class is using for holding the user's search preferences.
/// </summary>
public class Filter
{
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
/// <summary>
/// This class using for replacing characters like single quotes...etc in search string.
/// </summary>
internal static class UnwantedCharacterList
{
    public static KeyValuePair<string, string> Apostrophe = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("'", "''");

    public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> All
    {
        get { return new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { Apostrophe }; }
    }
}
```

So I would like to know if there is a more optimized way to do this that would give me better performance?

Comment: With the repeated replacements on the same source string, this is a bit of a 'schlemiel the painter' algorithm. Wonder if anyone has an improvement for that.

Comment: I think you are looping twice over both lists -> once for filtering, once for replacing. You could try to set the condition inside the inner .ForEach.

Comment: I hope it is not meant to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use a dictionary? I just want to learn when to use it over `List<KeyValuePair`...

Comment: @Eminem, I just opted it for performance optimization point of view. You can find some more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769053/when-would-you-use-a-listkeyvaluepairt1-t2-instead-of-a-dictionaryt1-t2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop won't have any effect, as your `list.Value` does not belong to any list. To save your changes your `lists` variable needs to be a List<> or array. It's easy to fix though - call `.ToList` on your original query if that's your intention.
Also, you keep talking about 'char' replacements, but your UnwantedCharacterList contain single-characters strings. Technically speaking they are not the same.

Now, if we talk about replacing, instead of inside `foreach` loop you can use `.Aggregate`:

```
list.Value =  UnwantedCharacterList.All
    .Aggregate(list.Value, (result, replacement) =>
        result.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value);
```

If you need to replace your "unwanted" characters in place, then you'll have to  stick to dhe external`foreach` loop.  If you are Ok to return a new sequence, then you can use a query:

```
var replaced = filterList.Select(filter =>
    new Filter
    {
         Column = filter.Column,
         Value = UnwantedCharacterList.All
            .Aggregate(list.Value, (result, replacement) =>
                result.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value), 
         Operator = filter.Operator
    });
```

I would also probably create a separate method inside `UnwantedCharacterList` which would incorporate `.Aggregate` call.

**Edit:** I was a bit too fast to advise using external `foreach` loop for in-place change. You would need to use `.ForEach()` method of `List` of course.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. will check that.

Comment: Great work!. Just tested all code with stopwatch. The code in question takes time {00:00:00.0019273}, and your suggestion of using .Aggregate in side first loop taken {00:00:00.0025421} and finally 'return a new sequence' taken just {00:00:00.0008119}. So going with the third option and marks this answer as resolved. Thanks!.