# Create complete set from a list with missing keys in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, arraylist, key-value

I've done a lot of digging and I can't seem to find an answer to this particular problem; answers to similar problems, but nothing quite like this.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is add missing keys with default values in a list. I have a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() with the below structure:

### Key : Value

```
name : Orange
actualname : Orango
name : Lime
fullname : Lime Lime
actualname : Limo
```

From the above list, I would like to create a complete set with missing keys in that set.

### Expected Key : Value

```
name : Orange
fullname : ""
actualname : Orango
name : Lime
fullname : Lime Lime
actualname : Limo
```

I am trying the below code:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "Orange"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("actualname", "Orango"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "Lime"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("fullname", "Lime Lime"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("actualname", "Limo")
};
var distinctKeys = list
    .Select(pair => pair.Key)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(pair => pair)
    .ToArray();
var lastKeyIndex = -1;

for (var index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
{
    var currentKeyIndex = lastKeyIndex + 1 == distinctKeys.Length ? 0 : lastKeyIndex + 1;
    var currentKey = distinctKeys[currentKeyIndex];

    if (list[index].Key != currentKey)
    {
        list.Insert(index, new KeyValuePair<string, string>(currentKey, string.Empty));
    }

    lastKeyIndex = currentKeyIndex;
}

for (var index = lastKeyIndex+1; index < distinctKeys.Length; index++)
{
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(distinctKeys[index], string.Empty));
}
```

But it's not giving me the expected output.

Another set to try:

### Key : Value

```
contacts.coid : 2003984
createdon : 2020-09-10
c_id : fcd5937d
contacts.coid : 2024489
createdon : 2020-09-10
contacts.fullname : Mark
contacts.coid : 99
c_id : 7e70096e
contacts.coid : 2024496
createdon : 2020-09-10
contacts.fullname : Simon
c_id : ebbbd1f4
```

**Expected Output**

### Expected Key : Value

```
contacts.coid : 2003984
createdon : 2020-09-10
contacts.fullname : ""
c_id : fcd5937d
contacts.coid : 2024489 
createdon : 2020-09-10
contacts.fullname : Mark
c_id : ""
contacts.coid : 99
createdon : ""
contacts.fullname : ""
c_id : 7e70096e
contacts.coid : 2024496
createdon : 2020-09-10
contacts.fullname : Simon
c_id : ebbbd1f4
```

Any ideas will be welcomed to solve this.

Comment: Suggestion: consider using a [Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1769053/421195), perhaps something like `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

Comment: @paulsm4 have tried, didn't work. can you please update the code accordingly.

Comment: @paulsm4 no.. you wouldn't use a dictionary here, you don't want unique keys.  @DaemonBee, is the data actually a text file; are you getting the data from a stream, or `string[]` or `string` to begin with (before this `list` representation)? do you already know exactly what keys\properties you'll be using in this sequence\set?

Comment: in the other set data, I think your expected output is not correct.  I think column order should be `c_id`, `contact.coid`, `contact.fullname`, `createdon`, as that is how I would expect a data dump to have output.. with identity fields on top, and audit fields on button

Comment: @Brett I have masked the data, hence probably it seems like an id field. These are all text fields.

Comment: @Hayden, any idea on the above sets

Comment: In general, I don't see how you can be expected to pull the desired final keys from the dataset as sorting the keys can potentially throw away the set ordering - imagine if the first set didn't have `contacts.coid` - how would you know the following `contacts.coid` started a new set?

Comment: The problem is that I can't see  automatic way to detect a boundaries between sets original list. If we follow the order, then for situation where first set has only `contacts.coid` value and second set has only `createdon` value - then how we can tell automatically that those two values belong to the different sets.

Comment: Of course if we have some mandatory field, for example `createdon`, and we know that values appear in the original list in same order for all sets - then we can group values into the sets correct and then generate "default" values for missing keys.

Comment: Thats the challenge and hence the problem is unique. Requires thinking to solve this puzzle.

Comment: alright, lets go back to pose the question that should have been posed from the very beginning. What problem are you facing in your attempt to solve this work problem?  I don't see anything wrong in your code or attempt; I ran the code snippet you provided and did get the expected output.  it is unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: see [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wb6Q9L) showing the results of both sets of data being run through your snippet.  Also note, that the second set outputs exactly as I had stated that I expected it to.. was that the issue you were actually having with this question and work problem?

Comment: @BrettCaswell no my current code snippet doesn't work for all. for example, `new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "Orange"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("actualname", "Orango"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "Lime"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("fullname", "Lime Lime"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("actualname", "Limo")` I am expecting a set like , name : Orange, fullname : "", actualname : Orango, name : Lime, fullname : Lime Lime, actualname : Limo

Comment: @BrettCaswell updated the key set accordingly to avoid any confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the first key for every grouping, you can group on that, you can create a complete list of keys ordered by the partial ordering from each set, and then expand each group to have a full set of keys.

First, some extensions on `IEnumerable` that let you group on a predicate (starting each group when it is `true`) and one for `DistinctBy`:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    // TRes seedFn(T FirstValue)
    // TRes combineFn(TRes PrevResult, T CurValue)
    // Based on APL scan operator
    // Returns TRes
    public static IEnumerable<TRes> Scan<T, TRes>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TRes> seedFn, Func<TRes, T, TRes> combineFn) {
        using (var itemsEnum = items.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (itemsEnum.MoveNext()) {
                var prev = seedFn(itemsEnum.Current);

                while (itemsEnum.MoveNext()) {
                    yield return prev;
                    prev = combineFn(prev, itemsEnum.Current);
                }
                yield return prev;
            }
        }
    }

    // returns groups of T items each starting when testFn is true
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupByUntil<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> testFn) =>
        items.Scan(item => (groupNum: 0, theItem: item), (a, item) => testFn(item) ? (a.Item1+1, item) : (a.Item1, item))
             .GroupBy(t => t.groupNum)
             .Select(tg => tg.Select(t => t.theItem));

    // returns a single item from each group of items by keyFn(item) picked by pickFn(itemGroup)
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> keyFn, Func<IGrouping<TKey, T>, T> pickFn, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null) =>
        items.GroupBy(keyFn, comparer).Select(pickFn);
}
```

Given the first key of each group:

```
var firstKey = "name";
```

You can now create a partial ordering of the keys based on where they appear in each set and then order the distinct keys:

```
var ordering = list.GroupByUntil(kvp => kvp.Key == firstKey)
                   .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
                   .SelectMany((g,sn) => g.Select((g, n) => new { g.Key, n = (sn+1)*n }))
                   .OrderBy(kn => kn.n)
                   .DistinctBy(kn => kn.Key, g => g.Last())
                   .ToDictionary(kn => kn.Key, kn => kn.n);
var keySet = list.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).Distinct().OrderBy(k => ordering[k]).ToList();
```

With the `keySet` you can expand each set of items to have all keys:

```
var ans = list.GroupByUntil(kvp => kvp.Key == firstKey)
              .Select(g => g.ToDictionary(l => l.Key, l => l.Value))
              .SelectMany(d => keySet.Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k, d.TryGetValue(k, out var v) ? v : "")));
```

If you prefer to have the final sets still grouped, just replace the `SelectMany` with `Select`.

Comment: There is no full list of keys for a complete set in proper order. It has to be derived dynamically from the given list only.

Comment: @DaemonBee In general, it isn't possible to derive the full list of keys when any key may be missing. There is no marker you can count on to distinguish between partial sets of keys. If you are willing to live with-in that limitation, or apply another constraint (such as keys are always in alphabetical order) that may be different.

Comment: you are right. The first column is mandatory. Can this be done assuming the first column will always be there.

Comment: @DaemonBee Yes, but note that your second example has a missing first column.

Comment: the set has been corrected to reflect the first column as mandatory

Comment: @DaemonBee Replaced my answer with one based on knowing the first column.

Comment: Thanks @NetMage for such acurate algorithm. Thanks again for your efforts to solve this.